# Myanmar font is not working correctly in jsPDF

Tags: jspdf

jsPDF custom font is not correctly working in Myanmar language.

I use [fontconverter](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html)  to add custom font in jsPDF.

This is the [original Myanmar text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6yri.png):
[image: original Myanmar text]

This is show [in jsPDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU8ba.png) :
[image: in jsPDF]

Please download [myanmar pyidaungsu font](http://www.unicodetoday.org/downloads/Pyidaungsu-2.5.3_Regular.ttf)

Comment: Can you describe what you see wrong with the jsPDF rendering? I suspect there most people here including me can't see a difference between the original and your rendering of the text beside some missing bolds and links.

Comment: @wilx   i use font converter from jsPDF official document link and then include that js in my project. After that in my code doc.setFont('Pyidaungsu-2.5.3_Regular');
   doc.setFontType('normal');

Comment: Is it the overflowing line in the middle that you see as wrong?

Comment: @wilx  No, e.g  **သုံးပြည်ထောင်ခေတ်**  this is correct text but when generate pdf is not correct, You can see at the first line of the this image [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU8ba.png)

Comment: I see what you mean now. I suspect jsPDF might not be dealing with contextual alternatives glyphs.

Answer (score 0):

jsPdf still doesn't support custom font.
It still is not working with Myanmar Unicode, but it can correctly render with Zawgyi-One font.

So, If it is okay with you, you can try Rabbit-node to convert your Unicode to Zawgyi font and then render with Zawgyi-One.